# Add row in each group using dplyr and add_row()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row, tibble

If I add a new row to the `iris` dataset with:

```
iris <- as_tibble(iris)

> iris %>% 
    add_row(.before=0)

# A tibble: 151 × 5
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>
1            NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA> <--- Good!
2           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

It works. So, why can't I add a new row on top of each "subset" with:

```
iris %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>% 
 add_row(.before=0)

Error: is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE
```

Comment: Upgrade your version of `tibble`, that error message is at least [three months old](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blame/b32c2b952afdeff93d422512a132ec6d0a2e2fbc/R/add.R#L35-L37). (The new error message says `"Cannot add rows to grouped data frames"`, which answers your question of why it is not working.)

Comment: You can use `do` to add row to each group: `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(add_row(., .before=0))`.

Comment: Thanks JasonWang and r2evans. I've updated my packages and using do() does the trick.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A more recent version would be using [`group_modify()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html) instead of `do()`.

```r
iris %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x,.before=0))
#> # A tibble: 153 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>    <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 setosa          NA          NA           NA          NA  
#>  2 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  3 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2
```

Comment: This should be used now instead of the `do` call proposed by @JasonWang in the OP's comments. `group_modify` preserves the group name when creating the new row whereas `do` does not, giving the user a value of NA for the grouped variable.

Comment: Just adding a comment years after I posted the question: group_modify is still in *experimental* phase as of May-2022. Thanks for the answer Alexlok

Comment: @Alexlok , I want the Species in NA rows paste '_blank'  :  group_modify(~ add_row(.x %>% mutate(Species=paste0(Species,'_blank')),
                         .before=0))  .But it's failed, how can i fix it ? Thanks!

Comment: @anderwyang Run the code as above without modification, *then* add this mutate line: `mutate(Species = if_else(is.na(Sepal.Length), paste0(Species,'_blank'), Species))`

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use a grouped operation, you need `do` like JasonWang described in his comment, as other functions like `mutate` or `summarise` expect a result with the same number of rows as the grouped data frame (in your case, 50) or with one row (e.g. when summarising).

As you probably know, in general `do` can be slow and should be a last resort if you cannot achieve your result in another way. Your task is quite simple because it only involves adding extra rows in your data frame, which can be done by simple indexing, e.g. look at the output of `iris[NA, ]`.

What you want is essentially to create a vector

```
indices <- c(NA, 1:50, NA, 51:100, NA, 101:150)
```

(since the first group is in rows 1 to 50, the second one in 51 to 100 and the third one in 101 to 150).

The result is then `iris[indices, ]`.

A more general way of building this vector uses `group_indices`.

```
indices <- seq(nrow(iris)) %>% 
    split(group_indices(iris, Species)) %>% 
    map(~c(NA, .x)) %>%
    unlist
```

(`map` comes from `purrr` which I assume you have loaded as you have tagged this with `tidyverse`).

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the thorough answer @konvas. FYI, no I didn't know do is slow and was not aware of the alternative with purrr/map. This is what makes SO great. Now I know where to look for answers to this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

With a slight variation, this could also be done:

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

iris %>%
  group_split(Species) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
            add_row(.before = 1))

# A tibble: 153 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1         NA          NA           NA          NA   NA     
 2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 5          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 6          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 7          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 8          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 9          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
10          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
# ... with 143 more rows
```

This also can be used for grouped data frame, however, it's a bit verbose:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Sepal.Length = c(NA, Sepal.Length), 
            Sepal.Width = c(NA, Sepal.Width), 
            Petal.Length = c(NA, Petal.Length),
            Petal.Width = c(NA, Petal.Width), 
            Species = c(NA, Species))
```

Comment: interesting approach with summarise. Wonder if it keep the groups names

Comment: summarise() approach worked perfectly for the work i was trying to do. Basically replace those NA with first()  or some other value `c(first(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length)`