# add specific new row using dplyr based on some conditions in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have df as below, I want to add a new row based on `ID` and `semester_num`. so far using `dplyr` would be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 group_by(semster_num) %>%
 #add new row here
```

I want the new row has all records similar to the previous row **except** the third column value (`subject_result2`) should be the same as column 4(`Success`) of the previous row.

```
tibble::tribble(
      ~ID, ~semester_num,   ~subject_result2,    ~Success,
  100000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
  100000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
  100000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
  100000L,             2, "MATH1PassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
  100000L,             2, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
  100000L,             2, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
  200000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm2", "fail",
  200000L,             1, "MATH1PassedTerm2", "fail",
  200000L,             2, "MATH1PassedTerm2", "fail",
  200000L,             2, "OTHERPassedTerm2", "fail"
  )
```

result: (I indicate the newly added rows)

```
          ~ID, ~semester_num,   ~subject_result2,    ~Success,
      100000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
      100000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
      100000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
 >>   100000L,             1, "Grad_ENSC",        "Grad_ENSC",
      100000L,             2, "MATH1PassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
      100000L,             2, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
      100000L,             2, "OTHERPassedTerm1", "Grad_ENSC",
 >>   100000L,             2, "Grad_ENSC",        "Grad_ENSC",
      200000L,             1, "OTHERPassedTerm2", "Grad_ENSC",
      200000L,             1, "MATH1PassedTerm2", "fail",
 >>   200000L,             1, "Fail",             "fail",
      200000L,             2, "MATH1PassedTerm2", "fail",
      200000L,             2, "OTHERPassedTerm2", "fail",
 >>   200000L,             2, "fail,              "fail
```

Please help to implement it in r. (it is totally fine to use other packages as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by combining `do` with `tibble::add_row`. I based this answer on the answer to this question: [Add row in each group using dplyr and add_row()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403282/add-row-in-each-group-using-dplyr-and-add-row), specifically the comment by [@JasonWang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5642068/jasonwang)

```
df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(ID, semester_num) %>%
    do(tibble::add_row(.,
                       ID = .$ID[1],
                       semester_num = .$semester_num[1],
                       subject_result2 = .$Success[nrow(.)], #Get the last row of the group
                       Success = .$Success[nrow(.)]))

# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   ID, semester_num [4]
       ID semester_num subject_result2  Success  
    <int>        <dbl> <chr>            <chr>    
 1 100000            1 OTHERPassedTerm1 Grad_ENSC
 2 100000            1 OTHERPassedTerm1 Grad_ENSC
 3 100000            1 OTHERPassedTerm1 Grad_ENSC
 4 100000            1 Grad_ENSC        Grad_ENSC
 5 100000            2 MATH1PassedTerm1 Grad_ENSC
 6 100000            2 OTHERPassedTerm1 Grad_ENSC
 7 100000            2 OTHERPassedTerm1 Grad_ENSC
 8 100000            2 Grad_ENSC        Grad_ENSC
 9 200000            1 OTHERPassedTerm2 fail     
10 200000            1 MATH1PassedTerm2 fail     
11 200000            1 fail             fail     
12 200000            2 MATH1PassedTerm2 fail     
13 200000            2 OTHERPassedTerm2 fail     
14 200000            2 fail             fail
```

Normally `tibble::add_row` won't work with a grouped data frame, but by using `do`, we can apply it to each group separately without leaving the pipe.