# How to add a row to each group and assign values

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have this tibble:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(id = c("one", "two", "three"),
             A = c(1,2,3), 
             B = c(4,5,6))

  id        A     B
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     4
2 two       2     5
3 three     3     6
```

I want to add a row to each group **AND** assign values to the new column **BUT** with a function (here the new row in each group should get `A=4` `B` = the first group value of column `B` **USING** `first(B)`-> **desired output**:

```
id        A     B
<chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     4
2 one       4     4
3 three     3     6
4 three     4     6
5 two       2     5
6 two       4     5
```

**I have tried so far:**

If I add a row in a ungrouped tibble with `add_row` -> this **works perfect**!

```
df %>% 
  add_row(A=4, B=4)

  id        A     B
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     4
2 two       2     5
3 three     3     6
4 NA        4     4
```

If I try to use `add_row` in a grouped tibble -> **this works not**:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  add_row(A=4, B=4)

Error: Can't add rows to grouped data frames.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

According to this post [Add row in each group using dplyr and add_row()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403282/add-row-in-each-group-using-dplyr-and-add-row) we could use `group_modify` -> this **works great**:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(A=4, B=4, .x))

  id        A     B
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     4
2 one       4     4
3 three     3     6
4 three     4     4
5 two       2     5
6 two       4     4
```

I want to assign to column `B` the first value of column `B` (or it can be any function `min(B)`, `max(B)` etccc.) -> this does not work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(A=4, B=first(B), .x))

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 'first': object 'B' not found
```

Comment: Can you translate "Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 'first': object 'B' not found"?

Comment: Something like: Error in evaluation of the argument 'x' within the method choice for function `first`; object `B` not found.

Comment: `first(.$B)` works for me.

Comment: If I add `first(.$B)` I get `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘first’ for signature ‘"numeric"’`

Comment: What about `group_modify(~ add_row(A=4, B=first(.x$B), .x))` or `group_modify(~ add_row(A=4, B=first(df$B), .x))`?

Comment: In both cases the same Error as described above with `first(.$B)`

Comment: I'm surprised that it works well for me but not for you, have you tried with another function, e.g. `head(.x$B, 1)`?

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you for your replies. I am wondering also why it does not work for me. Maybe you could post your code and output as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of the function [`group_modify`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html), if you use a formula, you must use "`.` or `.x` to refer to the subset of rows of `.tbl` for the given group;" that's why you used `.x` inside the `add_row` function. To be entirely consistent, you have to do it also within the `first` function.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(A=4, B=first(.x$B), .x))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id        A     B
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     4
2 one       4     4
3 three     3     6
4 three     4     6
5 two       2     5
6 two       4     5
```

Using `first(.$B)` or `first(df$B)` will provide the same results.

Comment: Bravo. That works. Sorry yesterday I thought I did the same .. and it did not work with your reply in the comments (today I am on a different setting...). Now it is clear and works perfect.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it works fine :)

Answer (score 5):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = c("one", "two", "three"),
             A = c(1,2,3), 
             B = c(4,5,6))

df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(add_row(cur_data(), A = 4, B = first(cur_data()$B)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>   id        A     B
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 one       1     4
#> 2 one       4     4
#> 3 three     3     6
#> 4 three     4     6
#> 5 two       2     5
#> 6 two       4     5
```

Or

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    group_split() %>% 
    map_dfr(~ add_row(.,id = first(.$id),  A = 4, B = first(.$B)))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   id        A     B
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 one       1     4
#> 2 one       4     4
#> 3 three     3     6
#> 4 three     4     6
#> 5 two       2     5
#> 6 two       4     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Yes! new_data were from the first edit that relied on list columns and unnest(). Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting and new to me, thank you for sharing this insight!!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is an option

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise( A=c(A,4), B=c(B,first(B)) ) %>% 
  ungroup
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  id        A     B
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     4
2 one       4     4
3 three     3     6
4 three     4     6
5 two       2     5
6 two       4     5
```

Comment: This is really a good option, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = c("one", "two", "three"),
             A = c(1,2,3), 
             B = c(4,5,6))

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(rep(1,2)) %>% mutate(A = if_else(row_number() > 1, first(df$B), A)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   id        A     B
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 one       1     4
#> 2 one       4     4
#> 3 three     3     6
#> 4 three     4     6
#> 5 two       2     5
#> 6 two       4     5
```

Comment: Very grateful for this version on how to add the rows!